# Use CreateProcess to run bat with spaces

Tags: batch-file, winapi, createprocess

The [CreateProcess documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that in order to run batch file one has to use `cmd.exe /C <path to bat>`. In fact it can run batch files just fine unless path to a script contains spaces (Microsoft confirms that in the description of the [MS14-019 vulnerability](http://blogs.technet.com/b/srd/archive/2014/04/08/ms14-019-fixing-a-binary-hijacking-via-cmd-or-bat-file.aspx)). I wonder if it's possible to escape spaces in the path to batch file to make CreateProcess work. Adding quotes doesn't help, CreateProcess fails with the error:

```
cannot spawn "<path to batch>": No such file or directory
```

**Update**

A workaround is to use short file names as pointed by @jac in the comments. I still wonder why enclosing a path in double quotes works for normal executables but doesn't work for batch files.

Comment: Use [ShellExecuteEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154.aspx) instead.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't own the code which calls CreateProcess, so switch to ShellExecuteEx or `cmd.exe /C` is not an option.

Comment: According to the body of your question, you already know the answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't.. did I miss something obvious?

Comment: Isn't the answer that what you are trying to do is not possible? That's what you appear to say in the question.

Comment: Have you tried converting to the DOS path? I.E. C:\PROGRA~1 instead of C:\PROGRAM FILES.

Comment: @jac: There's nothing *DOS* about [short path names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364989.aspx).

Comment: The description of MS14-019 doesn't say under what circumstances launching a batch file directly will or will not work.

Comment: @jac thanks, it helps! I still wonder why space in the .bat path breaks CreateProcess though..

Comment: @HarryJohnston true, that's why I ask

Comment: Since the fact that you can specify a batch file rather than an executable is explicitly contrary to documentation, there's no particular reason to expect it to work in every case.  All we can do is speculate.  My guess is that the code that handles that case is relatively primitive, and only kept at all because of backwards compatibility requirements.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I think you are right, I hoped that maybe someone saw CreateProcess implementation and can provide a workaround. BTW Solomon & Russinovich state that CreateProcess handles .bat files in a special way in their [Windows Internals 5th ed.](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2233328&seqNum=3) (see the table 5-6).

Comment: Interesting.  Fairly easy to see why it fails without the quote marks; cmd.exe is processing the command line, and it doesn't have the same logic as CreateProcess - the quote marks are mandatory.  Why it doesn't work with the quote marks is less obvious, but it may be as simple as the fact that the path ends with `.bat"` instead of `.bat`.

Comment: Actually I do have a copy of the Windows Research Kernel source at work.    That doesn't include the Win32 API, but I think it includes ZwCreateProcess which might (or might not) have the same logic.  I'll have a look next time I get a chance.

Comment: No luck, I reckon that logic must be in the Win32 layer.

Comment: @HarryJohnston thanks for checking!

Answer (score 0):

There is no escape character for CreateProcess.

Since the code is broken and you can't fix it, you'll have to work around the problem.  For example, create a junction point to the target directory and launch the batch file via the junction point path, or use short paths as jac suggested.  (Do note that not all volumes will necessarily have short paths enabled, but if you are dealing with the system volume it is probably safe to assume that they will be.)